# Countable basis

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be a locally compact subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$. I want to show that every component of $U$ has a countable basis.

Does $U$ just have one component, which is $U$ itself? 
Are the open balls with rationel radius and rational center a countable base for $U$?

Comment: There is no reason to assume that $U$ has only one component, try $U=\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be *any* subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. Then the open sets of $U$ are the intersections of $U$ with open subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. As this is the case in $\mathbb R^n$, every open set can therefore be written as union of open balls with rational center and radius (intersected with $U$).